# Integrate controlsfx 11.0.2 into JavaFX 14.0.1

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX, when integrating controlsfx 11.0.2 with JavaFX 14.0.1, then run mvn clean javax:run, the following error occurs:

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class impl.org.controlsfx.skin.NotificationPaneSkin (in module org.controlsfx.controls) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.ParentTraversalEngine (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal to module org.controlsfx.controls
```

Also I added the following VM arguments(in pom.xml) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/9.0.0/build.gradle):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
            <arg>--add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I used mvn -X to check runtime arguments and ensure the --add-exports already applied.

Comment: Those are [runtime](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/9.0.0/controlsfx-samples/build.gradle#L64) arguments, you will need to apply them to the `javafx-maven-plugin` (see https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxrun-options)

Comment: Thanks, @JoséPereda, really save lots of my time.